# JavaScript JSON data issue - alert not showing in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am having issues with some javascript code.

I am not getting the data alerted after the each loop area.

Here's the whole code:

```
var widget = {

    url: 'the url here', //no used yet

    readjson: function() {

       alert(this.url);   

       var  thedata = [
         {"TEST1":45,"TEST2":23,"TEST3":"DATA1"},
         {"TEST1":46,"TEST2":24,"TEST3":"DATA2"},
         {"TEST1":47,"TEST2":25,"TEST3":"DATA3"}
        ];

        alert(thedata); //I get this

            $.getJSON(thedata, function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index) {
                    alert(data[index].TEST1); //No alert here
                    alert(data[index].TEST2); //No alert here
                });
        });

    }

};

widget.readjson();
```

Comment: `$.getJSON(thedata` ??? You are passing array when this method expect a string URL. I'm not sure what you are expecting here?  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ Instead, explain your expected behaviour?!  I guess you want: `$.getJSON(this.url, thedata, function(data){...});`

Comment: If you comment `$.getJSON()` method, your code works as expected, maybe that's what you are trying to do/test?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[with a URL call :]
same code as below for JSON string, but wrap with the AJAX call :

```
$.getJSON('http://exemple.com/data.json' , function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      alert(this.TEST1);
      alert(this.TEST2);
    });
});
```

[with a JSON sting :]

```js
var widget = {
  readjson: function() {
    var stringJsonData = '[{"TEST1":45,"TEST2":23,"TEST3":"DATA1"},{"TEST1":46,"TEST2":24,"TEST3":"DATA2"},{"TEST1":47,"TEST2":25,"TEST3":"DATA3"}]';

    alert(stringJsonData);
    data = $.parseJSON(stringJsonData);

    $.each(data, function() {
      alert(this.TEST1);
      alert(this.TEST2);
    });
  }
};

widget.readjson();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

This is a JSON string that you can parse with [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) :

```
   var  thedata = '[
     {"TEST1":45,"TEST2":23,"TEST3":"DATA1"},
     {"TEST1":46,"TEST2":24,"TEST3":"DATA2"},
     {"TEST1":47,"TEST2":25,"TEST3":"DATA3"}
    ]';
```

The main issue is that you try to use an AJAX call (`$.getJSON()`) that take a URL string as 1st parameter, with a hand crafted json object thing...

For now, your is just a JS array of object you can process like this :

```js
var widget = {
  read: function() {
    var thedata = [{"TEST1": 45,"TEST2": 23,"TEST3": "DATA1"},{"TEST1": 46,"TEST2": 24,"TEST3": "DATA2"},{"TEST1": 47,"TEST2": 25,"TEST3": "DATA3"}];

    alert(thedata); //I get this
    $.each(thedata, function(index) {
      alert(this.TEST1); //No alert here
      alert(this.TEST2); //No alert here
    });
  }
};
widget.read();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, yes your code works now with the data I had. I've checked and the data is supposed to be JSON not the data I've got there. How can I change your example to read json instead if my data was in json format?

Comment: Yes, the end result will be to rest the json data via url

Comment: @Error2015 I've edit with a json string parsed, this don't use the AJAX call